# Organization Browser Performance

Tags: user-profile, performance, organization-browser

We have just launced our new SharePoint site. The Organization Browser seeks slow. We did not notice this in testing. Is there anything can be done to increase performance?

Answer (score 1):

Couple of steps possible -

1. Implement [Developer dashboards](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/Blogs/GetThePoint/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=457) - comes OOTB with SharePoint 2010. Activate this and you will be able to see all the bottlenecks your site faces and improve accordingly.
2. There is an awesome tool [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) which can be downloaded. This tool can give you a good representation of your site traffic. This can be used across browsers and its pretty handy when you have web parts that communicate to web services. This also gives you a good insight on areas that need to be improved.